# How to load dynamic components based on a property from object?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application, angular8

I'm trying to build a list of cards which may contain different components; So for example I have the following array of objects:

```
{
   title: 'Title',
   descrption: 'Description',
   template: 'table',
},
{
  title: 'Title',
  descrption: 'Description',
  template: 'chart',
}
```

I get this array as a response from a service, then I need to match each of thos objects to a component based on the `template` property, so for example, the first item should match to the `TableComponent` and the second one to the `ChartComponent`;

I'm trying to follow the Angular Docs regarding [Dynamic Component Loading](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#dynamic-component-loading), but I'm not sure how tell the method how to match each object in the array to a specific component.

In my parent component I have made an anchor point where the components should load with a directive:

```
<ng-template appCheckpointHost></ng-template>
```

And I'm trying to use the `ComponentFactoryResolver` as it shows in the example.

```
loadComponent() {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ChartCheckpointComponent);
    const viewContainerRef = this.checkHost.viewContainerRef;
  }
```

The example shows a scenario in which the "service" runs every three seconds, gets a random item, and shows it; but what I'm trying to do instead is to fetch all the items when the parent component loads, and render each item with its respective component.

Any ideas to get this to work?

Comment: you can use ngSwitch(https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch) to render component based on template value

Comment: @ajaiJothi yeah was kinda trying to avoid `ngSwitch`; I don't know but it feels like a more efficient way to use Dynamic loading? Could be wrong though, don't really know the advantages/disadvantages of the two

Comment: you need to use switch statement either in the template or ts file (if you are using componentFactory) - since you need to pass the component reference to `resolveComponentFactory`. I dont see a way to locate component dynamically based on a string value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary like:

```
const nameToComponentMap = {
  table: TableComponent,
  chart: ChartComponent 
};
```

And then just use this dictionary to determine which component should be rendered depending on the `template` property of particular `item` in your items array:

```
const componentTypeToRender = nameToComponentMap[item.template];
this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentTypeToRender);
```

Comment: That does look great, and say for the multiple components since it is a large array I should just put the `this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentTypeToRender);` inside a `forEach` loop? Sounds like the most obvious way to me

Comment: Yes, there is nothing hard here. Your can just loop over your array and pass dedicated type depending on `item.template`

Comment: Okay great; bad habit of mine to overcomplicate stuff, thank you very much, this does seem to take care of it pretty easily

Answer (score 1):

You can view my blog [here](https://ngohungphuc.wordpress.com/2019/08/22/create-and-destroy-dynamic-component-in-angular/)

First I will need to create a directive to reference to our template instance in view

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: "[dynamic-ref]"
})
export class DynamicDirective {
    constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}
}
```

Then we simply put the directive inside the view like this

```
 <ng-template dynamic-ref></ng-template>
```

We put the directive dynamic-ref to ng-content so that we can let Angular know where the component will be render

Next I will create a service to generate the component and destroy it

```
import {
    ComponentFactoryResolver,
    Injectable,
    ComponentRef
} from "@angular/core";
@Injectable()
export class ComponentFactoryService {
    private componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;
    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

    createComponent(
        componentInstance: any,
        viewContainer: any
    ): ComponentRef<any> {
        const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
            componentInstance
        );
        const viewContainerRef = viewContainer.viewContainerRef;
        viewContainerRef.clear();
        this.componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
        return this.componentRef;
    }

    destroyComponent() {
        if (this.componentRef) {
            this.componentRef.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally in our component we can call the service like this

```
@ViewChild(DynamicDirective) dynamic: DynamicDirective;

constructor(
        private componentFactoryService: ComponentFactoryService
    ) {

    }

ngOnInit(){
       const dynamiCreateComponent = this.componentFactoryService.createComponent(TestComponent, this.dynamic);
       (<TestComponent>dynamiCreateComponent.instance).data = 1;
       (<TestComponent>dynamiCreateComponent.instance).eventOutput.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
}

ngOnDestroy(){
  this.componentFactoryService.destroyComponent();
}

/////////////////////////////////
export class TestComponent {
  @Input() data;
  @Output() eventOutput: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  onBtnClick() {
    this.eventOutput.emit("Button is click");
  }      
}
```

Comment: How can I modify this to allow multiple different components to be rendered at the same time? By what I'm seeing I imagine it would have to be something regarding the code inside `ngOnInit()` maybe running those lines for each element in my array?